# Formato de numeros Oracle/Java

Tags: java, oracle

Tengo la siguiente consulta :

```
SELECT distinct ln.gps_id,GPS.LATITUD,GPS.LONGITUD,
to_number(substr(REPLACE(GPS.LONGITUD,'N',''),1,2))||'.'||TO_NUMBER(substr(substr(to_number(REPLACE(GPS.LONGITUD,'N','')),3,10)/60,2,6))||',-'||
TO_NUMBER(substr(GPS.LATITUD,1,3))||'.'||TO_NUMBER(substr(substr(REPLACE(GPS.LATITUD,'W',''),4,10)/60,2,10)) as data
FROM XXQP.XXQP_DIARIO_LN_TBL LN 
INNER JOIN XXQP.XXQP_GPS_TBL GPS
ON LN.GPS_ID=GPS.GPS_ID
WHERE LN.DIARIO_ID=355 
AND LN.GPS_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

Cuando la ejecuto en Toad arroja la informacion correctamente, sin embargo si este query lo pongo dentro de java me marca el error ORA-01722: número no válido, no se donde aplicar la conversion a numero o si necesito alguna otra cosa.

Saludos.

Comment: Sería bueno que trates de reducir tu consulta hasta aíslar tu problema.

Comment: El detalle esta aqui substr(substr(REPLACE(LONGITUD,'N',''),3,10)/60,2,6), pero ya le aplique conversion to_number y to_char, ninguna de las 2 opciones funciona. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código Java con el que haces la consulta?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema está en la división por 60 que estás aplicando a un VARCHAR2 y en el que Oracle está haciendo una conversión implícita.

Creo que lo correcto sería:

```
TO_NUMBER(substr(to_number(substr(REPLACE(GPS.LONGITUD,'N',''),3,10))/60,2,6))
```

Que realiza esta secuencia de operaciones:

```
vv = REPLACE(GPS.LONGITUD,'N',''); //varchar2
yy = substr(vv,3,10); //varchar2
xx = to_number(yy); //number
zz = xx/60; //number
ww = substr(zz,2,6); //varchar2
rr = TO_NUMBER(ww); //number
```